# Scala Get closest value in a map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I try to get the closed value in a map by key.

I have this map
val map = Map(1 -> "aaa", 2 -> "bbb", 3 -> "dddd", 5 -> "eeee", 9 -> "gggg", 100 -> "z")

if I ask for value with key 1, I should get "aaa", if I ask for value with key 6 I should get "eeee".

Any idea how to achieve this in a simple way ?

Comment: Your map doesn't have a 6. Why do you want 6 to pretend to be a 5?

Comment: What if you ask for `4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `SortedMap` for that:

```
def findClosest(map: SortedMap[Int, String], key: Int): Option[String] = 
  (map.to(key).lastOption, map.from(key).headOption).match { 
     case (Some((lk,lv)), Some((rk,rv))) if rk - key < key - lk => Some(rv)
     case (left, right) => (left orElse right).map(_._2)         
   }
```